# How do I remove kernel 3.5.0-36 from my system

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, kernel

I can see entry of 3.5.0-36 in my boot entry. But,I am unable to remove it as there is no package to remove.

See the command outputs from below for more details.

1) Command :

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Output :

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-75-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-72-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-36-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

2) Command :

```
dpkg -l | grep 'linux-image'
```

Output :

```
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic                    4.4.0-72.93        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic                    4.4.0-75.96        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic              4.4.0-72.93        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic              4.4.0-75.96        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                             4.4.0.75.81        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

3) Command :

```
uname -a ; lsb_release -a
```

Output :

```
Linux manish-Vostro-3446 4.4.0-75-generic #96-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:56:33 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Just use good ol' `rm` then. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Verify the file is in the `/boot`:

   ```
   ls -la /boot |grep '3\.5'
   ```
2. Remove the file. Be careful about spaces. This command will prompt before deleting each file

   ```
   sudo rm -i /boot/*-3.5.0-36*
   ```
3. Update your boot menu

   ```
   sudo update-grub2
   ```

Comment: I already knew that I could just rm it. But, will it be a clean removal ?? And how does it came there without any package ?

Comment: What do you mean without any package? You probably upgraded via your package manager and they removed the old kernel from their list. During installation they don't remove your old kernel though, sometimes the installation/update fails. To still be able to boot they don't touch your old kernels so you can select them during boot and still start your system.
Just remove them and update your grub and they will be gone.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "clean". As you have shown, there is no system installed package for this kernel.
I can only speculate as to how it came to remain in your system, but most likely answer is that it was there since before your upgrade to 16.04. It was likely your default kernel on your system before the upgrade.
If you want to see if there are other files that that were part of this kernel, try running
'find /usr/src |grep 3.5.0'

Comment: @sergtech :  the find command didn't revealed anything significant . Plus /usr/src contained only following directories/links : bbswitch-0.8, libdvd-pkg ,linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic, r8168-8.041.00,bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom,linux-headers-4.4.0-75, oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-xenial-0.201608190750~ubuntu16.04.1,nvidia-340-340.102,linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic,oem-audio-hda-daily-0.201610290546~ubuntu16.04.1,linux-headers-4.4.0-72,vboxhost-5.1.22

Comment: @sergtech : I modified your command a bit to find / |grep '3\.5\.0'  and ran intra-system search for the files. It revealed only following files in the system : /var/lib/initramfs-tools/3.5.0-36-generic , /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-36-generic, /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-36-generic . So, I think deleting all these three files should give a clean setup.

Comment: @Ziazis : A quick google search revealed that kernel to be of Quantal series. I never had Quantal on my system. My PC came pre-installed with Precise and I am only jumping versions via LTS .

Comment: @manishraj2011 Sometimes you have a newer kernel than your system should have because you enable backports? (Although you seem to be well versed in ubuntu to know if you did or not). I think you are close to having your system as clean as possible now :-). I would also recommend baobab as a graphical tool to look at your file system space usage if trying to save some space as well.